# Android convert ISO-8859-2 to UTF-8

Tags: android, string, utf-8, iso-8859-2

I'm downloading HTML source code of remote page into String variable. Unfortunetely the page is encoded via iso-8859-2 and contains characters from polish alphabet. How can I convert this string to utf-8, so I can display it's parts in TextView?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to "convert" the string at all, if you obey the `Content-Encoding` header sent by the web server.

Right now, you probably ignore that header while reading the response from the server (some `BufferedReader-to-StringBuffer/Builder` loop I assume), try this in your download code instead:

```
HttpResponse response = ....
String text = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

[EntityUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) will automagically use the content encoding specified by the server.