# How to handle Accent characters (like é in the word République) coming from the Google Map server as response in Android

Tags: java, android, utf-8

I want to display the response, coming from the Google Map Server. The response that I am getting is the name of a location that I am getting after sending the latitude and longitude to the Google Map server and the response is coming like this "av de la République" but when I am displaying this in the App after parsing the response, its getting displayed as "av de la RÃ(c)publique"....

The code snippet below might help in understanding my problem..

```
public static String getAddress(double lat, double lon){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         String add ="";

       try {

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lon+"&sensor=false");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        org.apache.http.HttpResponse response;
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            response = client.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       try {
          add = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
               .getString("formatted_address");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return add;
    }
```

This is my implementation of the code

```
public static String getAddress(double lat, double lon){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         String add ="";
        try {

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lon+"&sensor=false");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        org.apache.http.HttpResponse response;
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


            response = client.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            char[] buffer = new char[2048];
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8");
            while (true) {
                int n = reader.read(buffer);
                if (n < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                stringBuilder.append(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            Log.i("===================", stringBuilder.toString());
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


       try {

          add = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
               .getString("formatted_address");

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();

       }

       return add;

    }
```

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7368354/180100

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the text as bytes, rather than text. Which amounts
to reading the response in ISO-8859-1, when in fact it is UTF-8.

Try this:

```
char[] buffer = new char[2048];
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8");
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

while (true) {
    int n = reader.read(buffer);
    if (n < 0) {
        break;
    }
    stringBuilder.append(buffer, 0, n);
}
```

Here it is integrated into your code:

```
public static String getAddress(double lat, double lon){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String add ="";

    try {

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lon+"&sensor=false");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        org.apache.http.HttpResponse response;
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        response = client.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        char[] buffer = new char[2048];
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8");
        while (true) {
            int n = reader.read(buffer);
            if (n < 0) {
                break;
            }
            stringBuilder.append(buffer, 0, n);
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        add = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
        .getString("formatted_address");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return add;
}
```

Comment: Hello Esailija thanks for Answering my question. But I am not getting the desired result till now. Can you please implement your code snippet into mine and explain it a bit.

Comment: @Gulrez I am using `UTF-8` `Reader`, and reading the input to a `StringBuilder`. I have integrated it into your code

Comment: Hello Esailija thanks once again for replying to my post after integrating your code into mine, but unfortunately the problem is still not solved... I have posted my implementation of the code, it may help you in finding the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5730210

byte ptext[] = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");

If you are reading from a file you would also need to encode the inputStreamReader with UTF-8 encoding.

final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));